# Can we Find any Software's "Source Code" on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, software-center, source-code

I wanted to know that there's a software on Ubuntu store and if i installed it so as we know we are in Ubuntu Linux , can i find that software's **"Source Code"** on the Terminal or any Other way...
I am a student and have started Learning *Software Development*... So, How can i find any software's **"Source Code"** on Ubuntu
Please Help Anybody...

Comment: Software (or packages) found in 'multiverse' or 'restricted' won't have source available, but you can install source code for any 'main' (Canonical supported) or 'universe' (Ubuntu community supported) software packages. Source code, like binaries is built/packaged into packages, both come in the same way.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu